# Android MVVM: How to handle network request failiures?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am new to Android Arch components. I am trying to make a basic todo app using Android View Model and Live Data. What is the best way to make network calls when following MVVM pattern? I need to show a `progress bar` when a network request starts and dismiss it when the call is complete and in case of errors I need to display a `snackbar` with the relevant error message. Is it possible to do this without using an `AsyncTask`?

**Remote Repository Class:**

```
public class RemoteRepository {
private APIService apiService;

public RemoteRepository (APIService apiService) {
    this.apiService= apiService;
}

public LiveData<List<Project>> getList(String userId) {
    final MutableLiveData<List<Project>> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

    apiService.getList(userId).enqueue(new Callback<List<Project>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Project>> call, Response<List<Project>> response) {
            data.setValue(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Project>> call, Throwable t) {
            // What to do to show snackbar in activity
        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

Do we need to use an async task and manage the UI in its `preExecute` and `postExecute` callbacks? Or is it possible to do it with Observable Livedata objects?

Comment: go through https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample

Comment: @Raghunandan it's in Kotlin :|. Still, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @jaguar : It's a really good state of the art example app. I don't think that the programming language matter as long as you catch the basic ideas and architecture.

Comment: @jaguar i believe there is a java sample also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way.

Create a class that has a **Throwable** and desire success result object.
create a constructor or getter setter method to set values. ProjectRepoClass is an example of it.

**Project Repo Class::**

```
public class ProjectRepoModel {

private List<Project> mList;
private Throwable mThrowable;

public ProjectRepoModel (List<Project> mList) {
    mList= mList;
}

public ProjectRepoModel (Throwable throwable) {
    mThrowable = throwable;
}

public List<Project> getList() {
    return mList;
}

public Throwable getThrowable() {
    return mThrowable;
}

}
```

Set value according to API result. it can be an error or success response and return it.

**Return data:**

```
public LiveData<List<Project>> getList(String userId) {
final MutableLiveData<ProjectRepoModel > data = new MutableLiveData<>();

apiService.getList(userId).enqueue(new Callback<List<Project>>() {
    @Override 
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Project>> call, Response<List<Project>> response) { 
        data .setValue( new ProjectRepoModel (response.body()));
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Project>> call, Throwable t) { 
        data .setValue( new ProjectRepoModel (t));
    } 
}); 
return data;
}
```

Create Observable for live data in the UI part and make a check for error and display results according to it.

**Observe result In UI Like this:**

```
if (mModel.getThrowable() != null)
  {
        // Show error
  } else {

       // display success result

  }
```

This how you can achieve the error handle from the repository in MVVM.

Comment: using gnerics for ProjectModel would be good something like https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/vo/Resource.kt

Comment: @Jaymin Thanks I have added a throwable to all my response models.

Comment: Is it ok to use callbacks for this? Having an interface with 2 methods onSuccess() and onFailure() and providing its implementation in the viewmodel class?

Comment: @jaguar, Please accept the answer so it can be useful for other. Yes, you can use callbacks but it may cause the memory leaks or unwanted crash. so I would suggest that do not use callbacks.

Comment: Is it possible to return and observe multiple live data objects from ViewModel. 
For example one is the list of valid data and other is the error object. 
In fragment observing each live data. Is it allowed ? Should we do that